# Spring MVC: Avoiding file extension in URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've looked at this post: [Spring MVC; avoiding file extension in url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399487/spring-mvc-avoiding-file-extension-in-url)

This isn't working.... when I use

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring-MVC-Dispatcher-Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I get the warning

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CMT/WEB-INF/jsp/content/edit.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring-MVC-Dispatcher-Servlet'
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CMT/WEB-INF/jsp/content/edit.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring-MVC-Dispatcher-Servlet'
```

My default settings are using `*.htm` and the URL `http://localhost:8080/CMT/content/edit.htm`, but I'd like to be using `http://localhost:8080/CMT/content/edit`

I also still need to be able to load resources like js/css files located in `CMT/js`, `CMT/css` and `CMT/lib`

Comment: Your servlet mapping is OK. But have you defined a Spring MVC controller that cares about URLs like `/CMT/*`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No mapping found for HTTP request with URI \[/WEB-INF/pages/apiForm.jsp\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266303/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-web-inf-pages-apiform-jsp)

Comment: @krock - It's not, In the above example I'm using the fix suggested in that question

Comment: @AlexR - No, I suppose not... I don't want just any URL to work though.  If there's not a mapping for it I want it to fail.  I just don't want a file extension.

Comment: Show us your controller code - specifically your `@RequestMapping` annotations. Have you included * at the end of them: `@RequestMapping(value = "/content/edit*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you mapping you URLs correctly so as to catch both `edit.htm` and `edit`? Try (assuming CMT is your contextPath):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/content/edit*")
```

To get resources working, you need to specifiy `<mvc:resources .../>` in your spring config. See the [Spring doco here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources).

EDIT: Spring provides a `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` bean which usually catches possible extensions like .html, .xml, etc. The app I'm working on has this turned off via:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

So you should not have to worry about the extension normally.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a wildcard... maybe I put together `/content/editUsers/` or something... I want to be sure it doesn't match `/content/edit/`

Comment: Yes, you can use a `String[]` in the value part to specify it can match two or more URls: `@RequestMapping(value = {"/content/edit","/content/edit.htm"})`

Comment: if I do that though, it still won't match the `*.htm` in my `web.xml`.  I've already tried using `/*` there and it doesn't match.

Comment: There was no mention of `*.htm` in web.xml in your question... Spring recommends using `/*` (as did the other Q you referenced). Otherwise you're static resources won't work (*.js, *.css) without separate mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Include a directory component in the path.  (You probably do not want the mapping to match everything including internal requests.)