# How to configure Spring MVC DispatcherServlet to avoid url's with extensions?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, web.xml

I've a Spring (4.1.6.RELEASE) MVC project with a controller that is mapped to `/home`, but my problem is that it's also invoked for paths like `/home.html` or `/home.do`

My configuration is:

*web.xml*:

```
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

*main-servlet.xml*:

```
   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
   <!-- ... -->
   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
```

*HomeController.java*:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/", "/home"})
public class HomeController {  
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String doGet(Model model) {
        // ...
        return "home";
    }
}
```

As suggested in similar questions:

- [Spring MVC; avoiding file extension in url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399487/spring-mvc-avoiding-file-extension-in-url)
- [Spring MVC: Avoiding file extension in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703382/spring-mvc-avoiding-file-extension-in-url)
- [spring mvc how to bypass DispatcherServlet for *.html files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432788/spring-mvc-how-to-bypass-dispatcherservlet-for-html-files)

I've tried adding the following configurations:

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
      <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
   </bean>
```

and

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
      <property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="false" />
      <property name="useRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch" value="false" />
   </bean>
```

but without success.

When I debug the `DispatcherServlet` I can see that the instances of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` haven't set the above commented properties to `false`.

[image]

It seems that a simple configuration should do it, but I'm missing something that I'm unable to find out.

How should I properly configure the `DispatcherServlet` to avoid file extensions in mapped paths?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-path-matching) the config should be under `mvc:annotation-driven`, e.g.

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:path-matching suffix-pattern="false" />
  </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

as explained in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/PathMatchConfigurer.html)

> Whether to use suffix pattern match `(".*")` when matching patterns to
>   requests. If enabled a method mapped to `"/users"` also matches to
>   `"/users.*"`.     The default value is **true**.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That worked! If you could also provide the link to the docs It would be perfect.

Comment: sure thing, linked it know